# Can't edit stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using `\ef`. When I edit the function and then save and quit (vi), nothing happens.

Please help. I've been at this for two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) delivered to you:

> \ef [ function_description [ line_number ] ]
>
> This command fetches and edits the definition of the named function, in the form of a CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION command. Editing
> is done in the same way as for \edit.
>
> **After the editor exits**, the
> updated command waits in the query buffer; **type semicolon or \g to
> send it, or \r to cancel.**

You need to type in `\g` to save changes (issue a `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` command).